# asp.net entity model not loaded properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have generated an entity model from database, classes are generated perfectly but when i try to use "users.ToList" class it shows me error that there is no such method. Here is the action method in controller

```
public class LogController : Controller
{

    private myDBEntities2 db = new myDBEntities2();
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult checkLogin()
    {
        string name = Request["userName"];
        string pass = Request["password"];
        var u = db.users.ToList();
        foreach (var v in u)
        {
            if (v.userName.Equals(name) && v.password.Equals(pass))
                return RedirectToAction("items", "Product");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("login", "Log");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you included System.Linq namespace?

Comment: @KenDTimothy is correct you need to include `@using System.Linq` in order to use `.ToList()`